# Are most matrices diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, diagonalization

More precisely, does the set of non-diagonalizable (over $\mathbb C$) matrices have Lebesgue measure zero in $\mathbb R^{n\times n}$ or $\mathbb C^{n\times n}$?

Intuitively, I would think yes, since in order for a matrix to be non-diagonalizable its characteristic polynomial would have to have a multiple root. But most monic polynomials of degree $n$ have distinct roots. Can this argument be formalized?

Comment: A matrix can have a characteristic polynomial with a multiple root and still be diagonalizable (e.g. the identity matrix).

Comment: Right, but if the set of matrices with repeated eigenvalues has measure zero, then so does the set of non-diagonalizable matrices.

Comment: Sure, having a repeated eigenvalue is necessary for non-diagonalizability. However, I was just noting that it's not sufficient.

Comment: see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207723/my-proof-of-the-set-of-diagonalizable-matrices-is-zariski-dense-in-m-n-mathbb and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12657/proving-almost-all-matrices-over-c-are-diagonalizable

Comment: Hey OP, it wouldn't hurt to accept an answer by now.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Yes. Here is a proof over $\mathbb{C} $.

- Matrices with repeated eigenvalues are cut out as the zero locus of the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial, thus are algebraic sets.
- Some matrices have unique eigenvalues, so this algebraic set is proper.
- Proper closed algebraic sets have measure $0.$ (intuitively, a proper closed algebraic set is a locally finite union of embedded submanifolds of lower dimension)
- (over $\mathbb{C} $) The set of matrices that aren't diagonalizable is contained in this set, so it also has measure $0$. (not over $\mathbb{R}$, see this comment https://math.stackexchange.com/a/207785/565)

Comment: Good point. This is also pointed out here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/207785/565

Answer (score 8):

Let $A$ be a real matrix with a non-real eigenvalue. It's rather easy to see that if you perturb $A$ a little bit $A$ still will have a non-real eigenvalue. For instance if $A$ is a rotation matrix (as in Georges answer), applying a perturbed version of $A$ will still come close to rotating the vectors by a fixed angle so this perturbed version can't have any real eigenvalues.

Comment: Does this mean, almost all matrices are non-diagonalizable over R?