# Dimension of the space of matrices which commutes to an gaussian random matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, normal-distribution

Let $$ be an $×$ matrix with elements randomly sampled from standard normal distribution $N(0,1)$. Let $()$ denote the set of all matrices which commute with $$.

What is the dimension of $()$?

Comment: $A$ has distinct eigenvalues with probability $1$. It follows that $C(A)$ has dimension $n$ with probability $1$.

Comment: @BenGrossmann Could you explain why  has distinct eigenvalues with probability 1, and how to derive the dimension of () from the fact that  has distinct eigenvalues?

Comment: First of all, note that when I mean that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, I mean there are no repeated **complex eigenvalues** (that is, it is not sufficient to restrict our focus to real eigenvalues). For one argument that most matrices have distinct eigenvalues, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2329283/81360).

Comment: @BenGrossmann Got it! Then how to prove ()  has dimension  if there are no repeated complex eigenvalues for ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I note in my comment, a matrix $A$ with elements that are sampled from a normal distribution has distinct (complex) eigenvalues with probability $1$.

First of all, note that when I mean that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, I mean there are no repeated **complex eigenvalues** (that is, it is not sufficient to restrict our focus to real eigenvalues). For one argument that most matrices have distinct eigenvalues, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2329283/81360). As that post demonstrates, the set of matrices having a repeated eigenvalue has Lebesgue measure $0$. Because of the absolute continuity of the normal distribution (as a probability measure), we can conclude that the probability of $A$ having a repeated eigenvalue is $0$, which is to say that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues with probability $1$.

As for the dimension of $C(A)$ assuming that $A$ has distinct eigenvalues, we can proceed as follows. First, we consider the simpler case of matrices with complex entries. That is, we consider
$$
C_{\mathbb C}(A) = \{X \in \Bbb C^{n \times n} : AX = XA\}
$$
We will consider the dimension of this subspace of $\Bbb C^{n \times n}$ *as a vector space over $\Bbb C$*.

1. Note that if $S^{-1}AS = D$, then $X \mapsto S^{-1}XS$ is a bijective linear map that takes $C_{\mathbb C}(A)$ to $C_{\mathbb C}(D)$. It follows that $\dim C_{\mathbb C}(A) = \dim C_{\mathbb C}(D)$.
2. Show that if $D$ is diagonal with distinct diagonal entries, then $DX = XD$ if and only if $X$ is also diagonal. Conclude that $\dim C(D) = n$.
3. Conclude that if $A = S^{-1}DS$ and $D$ has distinct diagonal entries, then $\dim C_{\mathbb C}(A) = \dim C_{\mathbb C}(D) = n$.
4. Reframe the result as follows: the linear map $\Phi: \Bbb C^{n \times n} \to \Bbb C^{n \times n}$ given by $\Phi(X) = AX - XA$ has a kernel $C_{\mathbb C}(A)$, which has dimension $n$. Notably, $A$ is a matrix with real entries.
5. Use this to conclude (perhaps with the help [of this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2571197/81360)) that the linear map $\Phi:\Bbb R^{n \times n} \to \Bbb R^{n \times n}$ given by $\Phi(X) = AX - XA$ also has a kernel of dimension $n$. That is, $\dim C(A) = n$.